# Using hidden "form" to pass variables

Tags: php, variables

Just learning about passing variables from page to page in php, and trying to find the best way to do so for me, as I have to pass ~10 variables between 5 pages. On the first page, does it make sense to have a form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php $test ?>" />
</form>
```

Then on the next page could I receive this variable using `POST`? I would not like to have an ACTUAL form, just use it as a storage area for my variables. Also, what do I use for `action=` if the second page is called second.php.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you downvoted this, it's polite to explain *why* in the comments section.

Answer (score 7):

Short Answer: Forms only work when submitted. You probably want to use **[sessions](http://il.php.net/sessions)**.

Longer Answer:

- It does not make sense to have a form without user input. That's what it exists for.
- the `action=` attribute on a form reflects where the form would be submitted. If the processing page is `second.php` then the `action=` attribute should point there.
- Sessions are not the only possibility. PHP can also **[set cookies](http://php.net/cookies)**, and if the server doesn't care about the data (only being used as a medium), you can use HTML5's **[localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)**.

Comment: @SamCreamer To expand on Truth's answer, you should be aware that *some* users have their browsers set up to not accept cookies due to security precautions.

Comment: @Matt: Due to dumb security precautions, but yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Really, if you need to be passing 10 variables through all five pages, you're probably better off using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). You can store all of them as part of the `$_SESSION` variable and access them from any page as long as the session is kept alive.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use $_POST variables to store data in a user's session.

You should use:

- Sessions
- Cookies
- HTML5 storage

Comment: Note that the latter 2 can be freely edited by the user, while the former cannot.

Comment: @Lion: Why not? Cookies can be very useful for the use-cases it was intended for. Data required by the webserver which should persist long after the user has closed the browser window.

Comment: @Lion, what's wrong with cookies? User sessions are stored in cookies.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, you have various options:
1. Using a form and post as you outlined. In this case, on page 1 your action="second.php"
2. Passing the data via URL using GET
3. Sessions, as stated by the previous two posts
4. Cookies

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could try the following to POST your values without having the form appear on the page or actually be on the page at all. You need to have the jQuery library referenced in order to use this code.

```
    function hiddenPost(param1) {
        $('<form />')
        .hide()
        .attr({ method: "post" })
        .attr({ action: "http://my-URL-here.com/SomePage.php" })
        .append($('<input />')
            .attr("type", "hidden")
            .attr({ "name": "post_data" })
            .val(param1)
        )
        .append('<input type="submit" />')
        .appendTo($("body"))
        .submit();
    }
```

You can retrieve the POST values on the page you POST to in the same manner as if it was a regular POST with a form tag.

For PHP:
var postData = $_POST["post_data"];

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did this help you at all Sam?